# Stored Procedure does not call Update Command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure to Copy the data from various tables of security DB to Tenant DB.
In the procedure i am performing insert operation followed by a Update Query. Both of the commands should execute each time  the procedure but when i execute the procedure it does not execute the update query. Here is the structure of my procedure:

**COMPLETE SP:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [ams].[usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient] @ServiceIDs [varchar] (max)
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProcessID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @Steps INT

    SET @ProcessID = NEWID()
    SET @STEPS = 1

    EXEC usp_InsertServerProcessLog 'usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient'
        ,@Steps
        ,'Starting Procedure usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient'
        ,@ProcessID
        ,'Info'

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT *
        INTO #ServiceIDs
        FROM ams.SplitDelimiterString(@ServiceIDs, ',')

        SELECT BS.*
        INTO #tmpBkgServices
        FROM [AMS].[Syn_BackgroundService] AS BS
        INNER JOIN #ServiceIDs AS SI ON BS.[BSE_ID] = SI.Item
        WHERE BS.BSE_IsDeleted = 0

        SELECT *
        INTO #tmpBkgServicesWithChilds
        FROM #tmpBkgServices

        UNION

        SELECT MBS.*
        FROM #tmpBkgServices AS BS
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BackgroundService] AS MBS ON BS.[BSE_ID] = MBS.BSE_ParentServiceID
        WHERE BS.BSE_IsDeleted = 0

        SELECT #tmpBkgServicesWithChilds.BSE_ID AS Item
        INTO #ServiceID
        FROM #tmpBkgServicesWithChilds

        --for storing the Mappings for BkgAttributeGroupMapping and BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping based on Service IDs
        SELECT *
        INTO #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping
        FROM [AMS].[Syn_BackgroundService] AS BS
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping] AS BPAGP ON BS.BSE_ID = BPAGP.BSAGM_ServiceId
            AND BPAGP.BSAGM_IsDeleted = 0
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BkgAttributeGroupMapping] AS BSAGM ON BSAGM.BAGM_ID = BPAGP.BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID
            AND BSAGM.BAGM_IsDeleted = 0
        INNER JOIN #ServiceID AS SI ON BS.[BSE_ID] = SI.Item
        WHERE BS.BSE_IsDeleted = 0

        --For BkgSvcAttributes
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSA_ID]
            ,[BSA_Name]
            ,[BSA_Description]
            ,[BSA_Label]
            ,[BSA_DataTypeID]
            ,[BSA_IsRequired]
            ,[BSA_ReqValidationMessage]
            ,[BSA_MaxIntValue]
            ,[BSA_MinIntValue]
            ,[BSA_MaxDateValue]
            ,[BSA_MinDateValue]
            ,[BSA_MaxLength]
            ,[BSA_MinLength]
            ,[BSA_IsEditable]
            ,[BSA_IsSystemPreConfiguredq]
            ,[BSA_Code]
            ,[BSA_CopiedFromCode]
            ,[BSA_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSA_CreatedById]
            ,[BSA_CreatedDate]
            ,[BSA_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSA_ModifiedDate]
            ,[BSA_Active]
        INTO #tmpBkgSvcAttributes
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS BS
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BkgSvcAttribute] AS BSA ON BS.BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID = BSA.BSA_ID
            --AND BSA.BSA_Active = 1
            AND BSA.BSA_IsDeleted = 0

        --For BkgSvcAttributeOption
        SELECT [EBSAO_ID]
            ,[EBSAO_BkgSvcAttributeID]
            ,[EBSAO_OptionText]
            ,[EBSAO_OptionValue]
            ,[EBSAO_IsDeleted]
            ,[EBSAO_IsActive]
            ,[EBSAO_CreatedByID]
            ,[EBSAO_CreatedOn]
            ,[EBSAO_ModifiedByID]
            ,[EBSAO_ModifiedOn]
        INTO #tmpBkgSvcAttributeOption
        FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributes AS tmpBSA
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BkgSvcAttributeOption] AS BSAO ON tmpBSA.BSA_ID = BSAO.EBSAO_BkgSvcAttributeID
            --AND BSAO.EBSAO_IsActive = 1
            AND BSAO.EBSAO_IsDeleted = 0

        --For BkgSvgAttributesGroup
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSAD_ID]
            ,[BSAD_Name]
            ,[BSAD_Description]
            ,[BSAD_IsEditable]
            ,[BSAD_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BSAD_Code]
            ,[BSAD_CopiedFromCode]
            ,[BSAD_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSAD_CreatedById]
            ,[BSAD_CreatedDate]
            ,[BSAD_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSAD_ModifiedDate]
        --,[BSAD_IsRequired]
        INTO #tmpBkgSvcAttributesGroup
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS BS
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[Syn_BkgSvcAttributeGroup] AS BSAG ON BSAG.BSAD_ID = BS.BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId
            AND BSAG.BSAD_IsDeleted = 0

        --For BackgroundServices
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSE_ID]
            ,[BSE_Name]
            ,[BSE_Description]
            ,[BSE_SvcTypeID]
            ,[BSE_IsEditable]
            ,[BSE_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BSE_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSE_CreatedById]
            ,[BSE_CreatedDate]
            ,[BSE_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSE_ModifiedDate]
            ,[BSE_ClientCount]
            ,[BSE_ParentServiceID]
        INTO #tmpBackgroundServices
        FROM #tmpBkgServicesWithChilds AS tmpBS
        WHERE tmpBS.BSE_ID NOT IN (
                SELECT CBS.BSE_ID
                FROM ams.BackgroundService CBS
                )

        --For BkgAttributeGroupMapping 
        SELECT DISTINCT [BAGM_ID]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID]
            ,[BAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BAGM_Code]
            ,[BAGM_CopiedFromCode]
            ,[BAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BAGM_IsDisplay]
            ,[BAGM_DisplaySequence]
            ,[BAGM_IsRequired]
        INTO #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS tmpBAGBSG
        WHERE tmpBAGBSG.BAGM_ID IS NOT NULL
            AND tmpBAGBSG.BAGM_ID NOT IN (
                SELECT CBAGM.BAGM_ID
                FROM ams.BkgAttributeGroupMapping CBAGM
                )

        --For BkgAttributeGroupMapping - ALL ENTRIES
        SELECT DISTINCT [BAGM_ID]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID]
            ,[BAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BAGM_Code]
            ,[BAGM_CopiedFromCode]
            ,[BAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BAGM_IsDisplay]
            ,[BAGM_DisplaySequence]
            ,[BAGM_IsRequired]
        INTO #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS tmpBAGBSG
        WHERE tmpBAGBSG.BAGM_ID IS NOT NULL

        --For BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping 
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSAGM_ID]
            ,[BSAGM_ServiceId]
            ,[BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID]
            ,[BSAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BSAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BSAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_Code]
            ,[BSAGM_CopiedFromCode]
        INTO #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS tmpBAGBSG
        WHERE tmpBAGBSG.BSAGM_ID IS NOT NULL
            AND tmpBAGBSG.BSAGM_ID NOT IN (
                SELECT CBSAGM.BSAGM_ID
                FROM ams.BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping CBSAGM
                )

        --For BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping-AllEntries
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSAGM_ID]
            ,[BSAGM_ServiceId]
            ,[BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID]
            ,[BSAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BSAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BSAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_Code]
            ,[BSAGM_CopiedFromCode]
        INTO #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries
        FROM #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping AS tmpBAGBSG
        WHERE tmpBAGBSG.BSAGM_ID IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Inserting Data
        -- 1. Insert Data into Tenant Attribute from Security Attribute
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributes
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BkgSvcAttribute] (
                [BSA_ID]
                ,[BSA_Name]
                ,[BSA_Description]
                ,[BSA_Label]
                ,[BSA_DataTypeID]
                ,[BSA_IsRequired]
                ,[BSA_ReqValidationMessage]
                ,[BSA_MaxIntValue]
                ,[BSA_MinIntValue]
                ,[BSA_MaxDateValue]
                ,[BSA_MinDateValue]
                ,[BSA_MaxLength]
                ,[BSA_MinLength]
                ,[BSA_IsEditable]
                ,[BSA_IsSystemPreConfiguredq]
                ,[BSA_Code]
                ,[BSA_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BSA_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSA_CreatedById]
                ,[BSA_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSA_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSA_ModifiedDate]
                ,[BSA_Active]
                )
            SELECT [BSA_ID]
                ,[BSA_Name]
                ,[BSA_Description]
                ,[BSA_Label]
                ,[BSA_DataTypeID]
                ,[BSA_IsRequired]
                ,[BSA_ReqValidationMessage]
                ,[BSA_MaxIntValue]
                ,[BSA_MinIntValue]
                ,[BSA_MaxDateValue]
                ,[BSA_MinDateValue]
                ,[BSA_MaxLength]
                ,[BSA_MinLength]
                ,[BSA_IsEditable]
                ,[BSA_IsSystemPreConfiguredq]
                ,[BSA_Code]
                ,[BSA_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BSA_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSA_CreatedById]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[BSA_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSA_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSA_ModifiedDate]
                ,[BSA_Active]
            FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributes
            WHERE #tmpBkgSvcAttributes.BSA_ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT CBSA.BSA_ID
                    FROM ams.BkgSvcAttribute CBSA
                    )
        END


        -- 2. Insert Data into Tenant AttributeGroup from Security Attribute Group
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributesGroup
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BkgSvcAttributeGroup] (
                [BSAD_ID]
                ,[BSAD_Name]
                ,[BSAD_Description]
                ,[BSAD_IsEditable]
                ,[BSAD_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSAD_Code]
                ,[BSAD_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BSAD_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSAD_CreatedById]
                ,[BSAD_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSAD_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSAD_ModifiedDate]
                )
            --,[BSAD_IsRequired]
            SELECT [BSAD_ID]
                ,[BSAD_Name]
                ,[BSAD_Description]
                ,[BSAD_IsEditable]
                ,[BSAD_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSAD_Code]
                ,[BSAD_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BSAD_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSAD_CreatedById]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[BSAD_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSAD_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSAD_ModifiedDate]
            --,[BSAD_IsRequired]
            FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributesGroup
            WHERE #tmpBkgSvcAttributesGroup.BSAD_ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT CBSAD.BSAD_ID
                    FROM ams.BkgSvcAttributeGroup CBSAD
                    )
        END

        -- 3. Insert Data into Tenant BackgroundService from Security BackgroundServices
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBackgroundServices
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BackgroundService] (
                [BSE_ID]
                ,[BSE_Name]
                ,[BSE_Description]
                ,[BSE_SvcTypeID]
                ,[BSE_IsEditable]
                ,[BSE_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSE_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSE_CreatedById]
                ,[BSE_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSE_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSE_ModifiedDate]
                ,[BSE_ClientCount]
                ,[BSE_ParentServiceID]
                )
            SELECT [BSE_ID]
                ,[BSE_Name]
                ,[BSE_Description]
                ,[BSE_SvcTypeID]
                ,[BSE_IsEditable]
                ,[BSE_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSE_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSE_CreatedById]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[BSE_CreatedDate]
                ,[BSE_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSE_ModifiedDate]
                ,NULL
                ,[BSE_ParentServiceID]
            FROM #tmpBackgroundServices
        END

        -- 4. Insert Data into Tenant [BkgAttributeGroupMapping] from Security [BkgAttributeGroupMapping]
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BkgAttributeGroupMapping] (
                [BAGM_ID]
                ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId]
                ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID]
                ,[BAGM_IsEditable]
                ,[BAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BAGM_Code]
                ,[BAGM_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BAGM_IsDeleted]
                ,[BAGM_CreatedBy]
                ,[BAGM_CreatedOn]
                ,[BAGM_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BAGM_ModifiedOn]
                ,[BAGM_IsDisplay]
                ,[BAGM_DisplaySequence]
                ,[BAGM_IsRequired]
                )
            SELECT [BAGM_ID]
                ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId]
                ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID]
                ,[BAGM_IsEditable]
                ,[BAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BAGM_Code]
                ,[BAGM_CopiedFromCode]
                ,[BAGM_IsDeleted]
                ,[BAGM_CreatedBy]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[BAGM_CreatedOn]
                ,[BAGM_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BAGM_ModifiedOn]
                ,[BAGM_IsDisplay]
                ,[BAGM_DisplaySequence]
                ,[BAGM_IsRequired]
            FROM #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping
        END

        -- 5. Insert Data into Tenant [BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping] from Security BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping] (
                [BSAGM_ID]
                ,[BSAGM_ServiceId]
                ,[BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID]
                ,[BSAGM_IsEditable]
                ,[BSAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSAGM_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSAGM_CreatedBy]
                ,[BSAGM_CreatedOn]
                ,[BSAGM_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSAGM_ModifiedOn]
                ,[BSAGM_Code]
                ,[BSAGM_CopiedFromCode]
                )
            SELECT [BSAGM_ID]
                ,[BSAGM_ServiceId]
                ,[BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID]
                ,[BSAGM_IsEditable]
                ,[BSAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
                ,[BSAGM_IsDeleted]
                ,[BSAGM_CreatedBy]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[BSAGM_CreatedOn]
                ,[BSAGM_ModifiedBy]
                ,[BSAGM_ModifiedOn]
                ,[BSAGM_Code]
                ,[BSAGM_CopiedFromCode]
            FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping
        END

        -- 6. Insert Data into Tenant [BkgSvcAttributeOption] from Security BkgSvcAttributeOption
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributeOption
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AMS].[BkgSvcAttributeOption] (
                [EBSAO_ID]
                ,[EBSAO_BkgSvcAttributeID]
                ,[EBSAO_OptionText]
                ,[EBSAO_OptionValue]
                ,[EBSAO_IsDeleted]
                ,[EBSAO_IsActive]
                ,[EBSAO_CreatedByID]
                ,[EBSAO_CreatedOn]
                ,[EBSAO_ModifiedByID]
                ,[EBSAO_ModifiedOn]
                )
            SELECT [EBSAO_ID]
                ,[EBSAO_BkgSvcAttributeID]
                ,[EBSAO_OptionText]
                ,[EBSAO_OptionValue]
                ,[EBSAO_IsDeleted]
                ,[EBSAO_IsActive]
                ,[EBSAO_CreatedByID]
                ,GETUTCDATE() --[EBSAO_CreatedOn]
                ,[EBSAO_ModifiedByID]
                ,[EBSAO_ModifiedOn]
            FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributeOption
            WHERE #tmpBkgSvcAttributeOption.EBSAO_ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT CBSAO.EBSAO_ID
                    FROM ams.BkgSvcAttributeOption CBSAO
                    )
        END

        --for storing the Mappings for BkgAttributeGroupMapping and BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping based on Service ID
        SELECT *
        INTO #tmpClientAttrGrpAndSvcAttrGrpMapping
        FROM [AMS].[BackgroundService] AS BS
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping] AS BPAGP ON BS.BSE_ID = BPAGP.BSAGM_ServiceId
            AND BPAGP.BSAGM_IsDeleted = 0
        INNER JOIN [AMS].[BkgAttributeGroupMapping] AS BSAGM ON BSAGM.BAGM_ID = BPAGP.BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID
            AND BSAGM.BAGM_IsDeleted = 0
        INNER JOIN #ServiceID AS SI ON BS.[BSE_ID] = SI.Item
        WHERE BS.BSE_IsDeleted = 0

        -- for BkgAttributeGroupMapping
        SELECT DISTINCT [BAGM_ID]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAttributeGroupId]
            ,[BAGM_BkgSvcAtributeID]
            ,[BAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BAGM_Code]
            ,[BAGM_CopiedFromCode]
            ,[BAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BAGM_IsDisplay]
            ,[BAGM_DisplaySequence]
            ,[BAGM_IsRequired]
        INTO #tmpClientBkgAttributeGroupMap
        FROM #tmpClientAttrGrpAndSvcAttrGrpMapping


        SELECT *
        INTO #tempUnmatchedBkgAttributeGroupMap
        FROM #tmpClientBkgAttributeGroupMap T2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries T1
                WHERE T1.BAGM_ID = T2.BAGM_ID
                )

        -- for BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping
        SELECT DISTINCT [BSAGM_ID]
            ,[BSAGM_ServiceId]
            ,[BSAGM_AttributeGroupMappingID]
            ,[BSAGM_IsEditable]
            ,[BSAGM_IsSystemPreConfigured]
            ,[BSAGM_IsDeleted]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_CreatedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedBy]
            ,[BSAGM_ModifiedOn]
            ,[BSAGM_Code]
            ,[BSAGM_CopiedFromCode]
        INTO #tmpClientBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap
        FROM #tmpClientAttrGrpAndSvcAttrGrpMapping

        SELECT *
        INTO #tempUnmatchedBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap
        FROM #tmpClientBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap T2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries T1
                WHERE T1.BSAGM_ID = T2.BSAGM_ID
                )

        --do not delete
        --UPDATE [AMS].[BkgAttributeGroupMapping]
        --SET BAGM_IsDeleted = 1
        --  ,BAGM_ModifiedOn = GETDATE()
        --WHERE BAGM_ID IN (
        --      SELECT BAGM_ID
        --      FROM #tempUnmatchedBkgAttributeGroupMap
        --      );


        UPDATE BSAGM set BSAGM.BSAGM_IsDeleted=1,BSAGM.BSAGM_ModifiedOn=GETUTCDATE()
        from [AMS].[BkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping] BSAGM 
        join #tempUnmatchedBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap temp on BSAGM.BSAGM_ID=temp.BSAGM_ID

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        -- Drop Temp Tables
        DROP TABLE #ServiceIDs

        DROP TABLE #ServiceID

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgServicesWithChilds

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgSvcAttributeOption

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgAttrGrpAndBkgSvcAttrGrpMapping

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgSvcAttributesGroup

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgSvcAttributes

        DROP TABLE #tmpBackgroundServices

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgServices

        DROP TABLE #tmpClientAttrGrpAndSvcAttrGrpMapping

        DROP TABLE #tmpClientBkgAttributeGroupMap

        DROP TABLE #tempUnmatchedBkgAttributeGroupMap

        DROP TABLE #tmpClientBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap

        DROP TABLE #tempUnmatchedBkgSvcAttributeGroupMap

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries

        DROP TABLE #tmpBkgSvcAttributeGroupMapping_AllEntries
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        SET @Steps = @Steps + 1

        EXEC usp_InsertServerProcessLog '[usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient]'
            ,@Steps
            ,'Starting usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient catch'
            ,@ProcessID
            ,'Error'

        DECLARE @errorMessage VARCHAR(max)
        DECLARE @errorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @errorState INT;

        SELECT @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();

        SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();

        SELECT @errorState = ERROR_STATE();

        EXEC usp_InsertServerProcessLog usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient
            ,0
            ,@errorMessage

        RAISERROR (
                @errorMessage
                ,@errorSeverity
                ,@errorState
                );
    END CATCH

    SET @Steps = @Steps + 1

    EXEC usp_InsertServerProcessLog '[usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient]'
        ,@Steps
        ,'Ending Procedure usp_CopyMasterServiceDataToClient'
        ,@ProcessID
        ,'Info'
END
```

In the Code i am Using Ado .net to Call the procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection.StoreConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("ams.usp_CopyData", con);
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceIDs", SelectedServices.ToString());
                con.Open();
                Int32 rowsAffected = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    //some operation to perform
                    return true;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: You have a new `SqlConnection`, but do not have code to create and insert data into `#tmpBkgOption`, the proc will not go into update section

Comment: there is code to insert data in temp tables ...but i have not given it here

Comment: may you edit the question to incl. that? I think it should be after `con.Open();`

Comment: I see after the update you have rollback transaction, which reverses everything. Since you're using a transactions, put a try catch in your stored proc, and rollback when there's an error/exception. Or Instead of rollback transaction, you wanna put commit transaction

Comment: have you done a select statement using your update joins to see if there's data that matches between the 2 tables?